# vim hot keys with variables

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to do a mapping that moves the current line to another line. Something like

```
nnoremap < space >m$VARIABLE :m $VARIABLE <CR> dd
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with the basics, typing:

```
:.m15
```

Would move the CURRENT line ('.') to line 15.

Other than possibly creating a user-command which would accept a leading number indicating WHERE you want the current line to be moved, nothing comes to mind, nothing *SIMPLE* comes to mind.  (Rube Goldberg comes to mind...)

```
command! -nargs=0 MyMove :.m<count>
nnoremap! mv :MyMove
```

**MIGHT** work, my vim-fu is not strong yet.  You didn't supply much information, but that's close I suppose.